How to know if an object in a python module is imported or defined inside the module itself
let's assume i have two python modules a, and b.
a.py:
CONSTANT = 2

b.py:
from a import CONSTANT

CONSTANT2 = 4

if i use
b.__dict__

or
inspect.getmembers(b)

I get CONSTANT and CONSTANT2 but how do i get only CONSTANT (imported) and its parent module? or how can i filter the results to get only CONSTANT and its parent module?
what i want to have in the end is actually "a", the modules from which b imports
inspect.getmodule(CONSTANT)

doesn't work on integers or lists
i need this information to check that the dependencies are respected and that lower level modules do not import from higher level modules

What do you need that information for?

All imported modules are cached in sys.modules, so you can build with it a mapping of names to belonging modules, with which you can filter the current module's global variables. Since you likely aren't interested in names of the imported modules themselves (such as sys), you can further filter names whose values are of module type:
import sys
from a import CONSTANT

imported = {
    name: module for module in sys.modules.values() for name in vars(module)
    if not (name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')) # exclude dunders
}
ModuleType = type(sys)
print(*(
    (name, imported[name].__name__) for name, obj in globals().items()
    if name in imported and not isinstance(obj, ModuleType)
), sep='\n')

This outputs:
('CONSTANT', 'a')

